# Popup message : Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '403'. The status text of response is 'Forbidden'

Tags: file-upload, popup, 403, links

When I edit my page and add some link like in picture below:

[image]

I can successfully added the link but when I click on Display Icon under Link Tab:,

[image]

I got this popup message.

[image]

could not understand, Whats wrong ?

Comment: Is the popup error occurring when you click the link, or when you save the page?

Comment: popup comes up when i check Display icon checkbox!!

Comment: Is the designated link to a file?

Comment: yes, for example when i add a link to a pdf file and check Display icon checkbox, this popup comes up!!

Comment: And is the path you're providing to the file relative or absolute?

Comment: its absolute. for adding document, i click on Link -> From Sharepoint -> and then chose document from Documents library.

Comment: please check user permissions on page , for that erros check similar issues https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/b2579ef2-18c4-410d-bc91-88f34a05dc79/sharepoint-online-error?forum=sharepointgeneral